# How to execute schedular for data stored in .config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduler

In my application data is stored in a .config file,(in XML format). User is able to set date on which he wants mail (like reminder through mail). So there should be a scheduler which will execute daily to send mails on target date to users. As there is no database interaction how is it possible to run scheduler?

I am totally blank about this task. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an application running in background checking periodically if it is time to do a task. A windows service is what I use frequently for this kind of tasks. Or you can programatically create a windows scheduled task to run your app.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the windows scheduler service that will run any exe, alternatively if the process is significantly complex you could create your own service.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the window scheduler or service which suits you best but apart from that you have the option in web application also through which you can run the scheduled task. For that you have to use the goabal.asax file .It will run after every 60 minutes .
global.asax code is as follows ::

```
<code>
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    private const string DeliveryPageUrl = "http://put any test url of your application";

    private const string DummyCacheItemKey = "Any hard coded value";  // you can put any name here DummyCacheItemKey = "gigigagagugu";

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterCacheEntry();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the dummy page is hit, then it means we want to add another item
        // in cache
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == DeliveryPageUrl)
        {
            // Add the item in cache and when succesful, do the work.
            RegisterCacheEntry();
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Register a cache entry which expires in 60 minute and gives us a callback.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private void RegisterCacheEntry()
    {
        // Prevent duplicate key addition
        if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[DummyCacheItemKey]) return;

        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(DummyCacheItemKey, "Test", null, DateTime.MaxValue,
                                        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                                        new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Callback method which gets invoked whenever the cache entry expires.
    /// We can do our "service" works here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="reason"></param>
    public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        // We need to register another cache item which will expire again in one
        // minute. However, as this callback occurs without any HttpContext, we do not
        // have access to HttpContext and thus cannot access the Cache object. The
        // only way we can access HttpContext is when a request is being processed which
        // means a webpage is hit. So, we need to simulate a web page hit and then 
        // add the cache item.
        HitPage();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hits a local webpage in order to add another expiring item in cache
    /// </summary>
    private void HitPage()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        client.DownloadData(DeliveryPageUrl);
    }
    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>

   </code>
```